# React native project installation error - cannot execute binary file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, binary

`npx react-native run-android`

`/var/folders/7f/jpn548vn4ns3lq7chr50nb_h0000gn/T/npx-d96401db.sh: line 1: /Users/node_modules/.bin/react-native: cannot execute binary file`

1. project file is not installing, when use cmd to install the file it shows the error - cannot execute binary file
2. how to solve this error